# Function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am trying to use `node-pg-migrate` and run migrations to create tables in my node project.
When I run migrations I get function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist.

I did check in my extensions and uuid-ossp is available.

```
extname  | extowner | extnamespace | extrelocatable | extversion | extconfig | extcondition 
-----------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------
 plpgsql   |       10 |           11 | f              | 1.0        |           | 
 uuid-ossp |    16384 |         2200 | t              | 1.1        |           | 
(2 rows)
```

I expect my migrations to run but it fails. I am using Postgres 11 on Mac.
Postgres installed from here - https://postgresapp.com/

Comment: I hope you have not encountered the same problem as this: https://github.com/salsita/node-pg-migrate/issues/401#issuecomment-466891346

Answer (score 39):

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Comment: you also need to have `uuid-ossp.control` extension to be available provided by `postgresql-contrib` package

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not have much information about what your pg-migrate files look like, but you must specify the following:

```
pgm.createExtension('uuid-ossp', { ifNotExists: true });
// and
pgm.createTable('my_table', {
    id: { type: 'uuid', primaryKey: true, default: new PgLiteral('gen_random_uuid()') },
    // ...
```

Comment: Hey, I tried that and it still says function not found. I must be doing something really silly. Somewhere I found its not in right schema, I even put that and it still gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the create extension must be in a different transaction. Practically it means to have one migration for creating the extension. Only in later migration create the table with the `uuid_generate_v4` function.